# How to pass parameter to testng in command line?

Tags: java, testng

Is it possible to pass parameter to testng in command line?

Like parameter for maven: `mvn testname -Dparam1=value1 -Dparam2=value2`

I know how to use and actually use:

- testng.xml (params & test classes, methods to be executed)
- DataProvider (to pass test data)

But there is one param that should be passed in command line - `serverName`, e.g.:

```
java -cp "/opt/testng-6.8.jar:bin" org.testng.TestNG testng.xml -Dservername=srv1
```

Reason: do not want to have dozens of `testng-srv1.xml, testng-srv2.xml ...` for each `test suite` X `server`.

Comment: What's the problem with doing it exactly like that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`java` is treating `-Dservername=srv1` as a command line argument to `org.testng.TestNG` and not as one of its options. You need to move `-Dservername=srv1` to before the "class" option (i.e. before `org.testng.TestNG`). e.g.:

```
java -cp "/opt/testng-6.8.jar:bin" -Dservername=srv1 org.testng.TestNG testng.xml
```

Answer (score 2):

You may have to shift the `-Dservername=srv1` part before `org.testng.TestNG`. Try the following:

```
java -cp "blabla" -DparameterName=value org.testng.TestNG testng.xml
```

Additionally, I would suggest to NOT add this parameter in your testng.xml file. Otherwise, it will override this value.